# Tableau - Filter/Parameter For Different Date Ranges

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to set up a filter or parameter for different date ranges in Tableau, such as:

1. Previous Week
2. Previous 4-Weeks
3. Previous 8-Weeks

based on the most recent data in the database. Is this possible?

**Edit**:
I should have been more clear here.

Is it possible to only have these options in the filter and have it based on the maximum date in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

Based on your comment and updated question, you can do it as you intend, though it isn't as straight-forward.

> NOTE: I did this very quickly and with a random data set, so it will be important for you to test this thoroughly with your data set.

Steps:

1. Create a parameter control that the users will use to change the selected date range. I created this as a list of strings with values that I can use directly in a calculated (after simple casting):

[image]

2. Create a calculated field that you will use as a filter that references the selection of the parameter control. It tests to see if the difference (in weeks) between the maximum date in the view and the date of any given row is less than the value of the parameter.

[image]

Calculation: `INT([Date Filter Parameter]) > DATEDIFF("week",ATTR([Date Field]),WINDOW_MAX(MAX([Date Field])))`

3. Place the calculated field in the filter box and set it to `True`.

You will be able to filter your data like so:

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

### Original Answer

Yup - that is built into Tableau.

Add your date to the filter and select the "Relative Date" option:

[image]

You can set the defaults - users can change these later:

[image]

Then just "Show Filter":

[image]

Comment: I should have been more clear here.

Is it possible to only have these options in the filter and have it based on the maximum date in the database?

Comment: @Nicarus Good revised answer, but there is still one issue. The table calc doesn't look at the last date in the database as requested, but looks at the last date in the current partition of query results. That could be very different.

Instead define an LOD calc called "Last_Date = {MAX([Date Field])} and use that instead of WINDOW_MAX (or just replace WINDOW_MAX with a left curly brace in line and close appropriately)

Comment: @AlexBlakemore - Until I know what the OP's dataset looks like - there is not much I can expand on.

Comment: @AlexBlakemore This worked for me. I ran into another issue. I have to implement not just previous week, previous 4 weeks and previous 8 weeks, but have to add previous two week by itself. Is this possible? So something like:

`1. Previous Week
2. Previous 2 Weeks (This week alone)
3. Previous 4 Weeks`

Comment: Yes, the approach @Nicarus showed is very general. You can extend it however you need. Just have a parameter choice for each setting that the user may request, and revise your calculated field to look at the parameter value and the field values in the current record, and return true if that record should be included in the viz. Read about the various Date related functions in the Tableau docs, such as DateDiff, DateTrunc, DateAdd