# Set Time Period Date Filters For Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Is there a method to create a parameter/filter which allows you to switch set time periods based on date?

For example I need to create a filter with the following options:

1. Most current week from last date in database (Max Date minus 7)
2. Previous Week from last date in database (Current Week minus 7)
3. Previous 4 Weeks (Max Date minus 28)

I would need to have only these options to choose from the filter available for the user.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951031/tableau-filter-parameter-for-different-date-ranges

Comment: Yes, but my previous week question was not addressed. The answer gave me previous two weeks instead of previous week alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem here is how to reference the last date in the data. Simple `MAX([Order Date])` doesn't work, because it is dependent on filters and sheet layout, i.e. it will give you filtered date or multiple dates, or both. Assuming you are using the latest version and your data source supports [LOD calculations](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html), you can use those, e.g. `{MAX([Order Date])}` (note curly braces).

The other problem is that your date ranges overlap, so a simple IF-THEN will not work, because with IF-THEN each date can belong to only one range of interest, i.e. it can't handle overlap. Try it to see the effect.

So, to work around the second problem, you can create three calculated fields (one for each range) that return a Boolean (you may need to modify the formulas to suit your needs):

Is last 7 days:

```
[Order Date] >= {MAX([Order Date])} - 7 
            AND [Order Date] < {MAX([Order Date])}
```

Is 2nd last week:

```
[Order Date] >= DATETRUNC('week',{MAX([Order Date])},'Monday') - 7 
        AND [Order Date] < DATETRUNC('week',{MAX([Order Date])},'Monday')
```

Is last 28 days:

```
[Order Date] >= {MAX([Order Date])} - 28 
        AND [Order Date] < {MAX([Order Date])}
```

These formulas will tag each date independently of each other, ignoring overlaps.

Then you have to create a parameter to allow user to specify which range to show. The parameter is a list of 3 string values, indicating the range choice. I named this parameter 'Show Days'.

Finally, create the calculated field that will be placed on the filter:

```
([Is last 7 days] AND [Show Days] = 'last 7 days')
OR
([Is 2nd  last week] AND [Show Days] = '2nd last week')
OR 
([Is last 28 days] AND [Show Days] = 'last 28 days')
```

Put it on the filter shelf, select 'True', show parameter control and select the desired value.

Comment: This was perfect. Thanks! @Dimitri B