# How to get a date range parameter in Tableau Dashboard?

Tags: tableau-api

I am relatively new to Tableau and was trying to create a relative date range parameter in my tableau dashboard, I am using SQL server DB as my data source with custom SQL.

```
I created a date parameter in my tableau sheet,  and it is set from a date key field from database. 

 [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYziI.png

```
I used the same parameter to create a True False statement for my worksheet.
```

[image]

After this I created a dashboard with my worksheet and tried filtering out based on range of dates. But I am not able to get range of dates and unable to link dates with the values present in database.

Suppose when I go to a Sheet, and try to filter out based on this FullDateAlternatekey, I can see the relative date range selection and can filter out results.

[image]

I created dashboard based on the sheet and used the same parameter being used in the sheet but I am unable to filter out results, and also I am not getting option to have relative dates where I could filter by weeks, years, and other attributes.

This is how my dashboard looks. [image]

There is no data for 2018 and also I don't see any options for relative dates.

I looked into this [Tableau - Filter/Parameter For Different Date Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951031/tableau-filter-parameter-for-different-date-ranges) but did not work. Is there something I am missing to create this date link and have relative dates on my dashboard?

Comment: Parameters will only ever return a single value, not a range.  Why not just use your date dimension directly as a filter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are messing few things here:

1. When you created a field `DateKey` then remove `fulldatealternatekey` from filters part
2. Now when you place `datekey` in filters which is a boolean filed you need to select either true or false depending on your requirement, As per my understanding you need to select `true` so uncheck remaining options.

Now what is your relative date requirement because this will change the logic of `Datekey`

Comment: Thank You for the information, and your effort. For relative date, if you see my Filter (FullAlternateDatekey) in the screenshot above in my work book  it shows relative dates (Year, Quarters, Week, Month and other options)

Comment: @Avi ok so you want to implement the same functionality that tableau is providing, fine in this case what are the possible scenarios for years, quarters etc. For e.g if you select `years` option then do you want to see the data for the years selected before the current date? can you be more specific?